# Connecting to webservice from BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

I am connecting to a web server from a BlackBerry simulator for the 9630, to get an image and display it on screen.

But while testing this same app in the 8520 and 9700 simulators, it doesn't work.  I think it didn't connect to the web service.

I need to be able to connect to a web service from all simulators.

```
String filepath="file:///store/home/user/loan1.jpg";
FileConnection fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open(filepath,Connector.READ_WRITE);
String photoXml=
    "<MortgageGetPhoto><LoanOfficerID>82</LoanOfficerID></MortgageGetPhoto>";
byte[] imgArry=
    Base64InputStream.decode(new DataParsingComm().ILGetImage(photoXml));
EncodedImage image = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(imgArry,0,imgArry.length);

BitmapField bitf=new BitmapField() {
    public void layout(int width, int height) {
        super.layout(100, 100);
    }
};
bitf.setImage(image);
HorizontalFieldManager bfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(FIELD_HCENTER); 
bfm.add(bitf);

add(bfm);
```

Comment: You don't need to start every question with "I am new to blackberry"

Comment: really i am new to blackberry.So i am using new to blackberry for every question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think it didn't connect to the web service.

It seems you should verify this before asking your question.  Set a breakpoint in the debugger, and see where code execution fails.

Answer (score 0):

Have you opened the mds simulator? The simulator needs it to access internet.

Comment: That is not correct. The simulator can do TCP without the MDS simulator if you append `;deviceside=true` to the URL or configure a WLAN network. Your application just needs to figure out which type of connection works. That is usually a good idea anyway, because often some connection methods work while others do not work, even if they are available.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have MDS turned on.  Use JSR172 webservices (see NetBeans documentation), and I don't think you can transfer and image direclty, you'll need to transfer a byte array.